# how to arrest sudden spike value occurs occasionally in sensor using embedded c

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded, sensors, calibration

I'm working with sensor with amplifier. I can see sensor is suddenly producing very high value, which is affecting the functionality. I'm looking for some algorithm that will eliminate sudden spike values. I'm using embedded c for this project, please suggest me some algorithm that will eliminate sudden spike values using c program.

I tried previous and current value comparison method but it has not solved my problem

Comment: Usual way is to compute `savg` (sliding average) of the signal `x` on the run and detect spike `if (abs(x-savg(x))>_some_threshold) /* here spike is detected */ ;` however without  sample input we can only guess... `svg(x(t)) = ( x(t-n)+ ... +x(t-2)+x(t-1)+x(t)+x(t+1)+x(t+2)+ ... +x(t+n) )/(n+n+1);` so just average `2n+1` consequent values of `x` which will give you the value of middle of the averaged values this can be easily done with ring buffer or FIFO if you average power of 2 values instead of `2n+1`  then you can use bitshift instead of `/` at the cost of slight time shift...

Comment: Assuming that the value range is the whole range of for example an ADC from 0 to Vref, then we can't really set threshold values. If we have specific knowledge of the system, we can however predict how fast the values ought to be shifting. For example if we control some actuator or valve using a PWM current, the measured current shouldn't deviate too much from the output or something is off.

Comment: Firstly it is probably better to find the root cause of the spikes and glitches on your sensor rather than disguise the problem in software. If you want a rough and ready quick fix then a sliding boxcar average of an odd number of samples is OK and unbiassed. You should probably record bad values but replace them with the boxcar average if they are jumping way beyond 3 sigma noise level for feeding to any control algorithm. I'd caution against filtering the raw data you can't get back raw data that has been tweaked. But provide a sanitised stream to the customer.

Comment: @MartinBrown "sliding boxcar" is called "sliding average" ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that a digital average filter works exactly like a RC filter in hardware: it doesn't eliminate anything, just round it down. If the spikes are part of the expected input, you can use an average filter.

But if spikes are anomalies that should just get ignored, then to *eliminate* spikes rather than "down tuning" them, you need to use a median filter. Often called median-3 or median-5 etc depending on how many previous samples you store. The sample rate needs to be long enough that a spike only occurs during 1 sample, or otherwise you are arguably dealing with surges, not spikes - or just sampling too fast.

How do code them depends on if you are reading digital or analog input.

Digital input is as simple as storing a sequence of 1 or 0 in the order of appearance. Suppose 0 is the expected value, then you can do a table lookup on `001`, the "median-3" value of that is 0.

For analog input you have to sort the values as they come in. Some examples can be found here: https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2010/10/median-filtering/ There are ways to optimize that code further, but it should work as a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple moving average filter like

```
#define N 5

int sensorData[N];
int currentIndex = 0;

int FilterSensorData(int newData) {
    sensorData[currentIndex] = newData;

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        sum += sensorData[i];
    }

    int movingAverage = sum / N;    
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % N;

    return movingAverage;
}
```

Select N depending on your needs.

I do not know the details of your sensor data. You can change integers with float types if your sensor data is in real numbers.

Comment: Spikes should most often be eliminated with a _median_ filter, not an average filter. Or otherwise you let spikes affect the output.

Comment: A fair point if the spike is a single sample but it gets tricky if the spike is some sort of real physical process affecting several consecutive samples. For this reason it is usually best to save unmolested raw data and feed sanitised data to any customers and use the output of the boxcar average to replace any spiked samples in the average.